# Word continuous section break causes blank page

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I have the following problem: for my thesis I use Word 2016 and I have to put many continuous section breaks that interfere with footnotes causing unexpected page jumps. I used the fix MS suggested (https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/292074/section-break-causes-an-unexpected-page-break-in-word) but it still doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

### Why do you have many section breaks? This is very unusual.

Look into using the [StyleRef Field](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm#STYLEREF) if you are trying to change text in your headers and footers using section breaks. *Disclosure: Link is to page on my website.*

### Continuous Section Breaks are for changing columns within a document. That is about it.

Other uses would call for a section break that adds a page like Next Page, Odd Page or Even Page. You should *almost never* be changing **Margins** within a document and ***never*** with a continuous section break. While Word allows changing margins within a page, this is very poor practice and greatly complicates document files without any reason. Change paragraph indents instead. See [Margins and Indents in Word](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/basic_formatting.htm#Margins_and_Indents). *(also on my web site)*

### For unexpected spacing on pages, see [Improving the Bottom Line](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/BottomLine.htm) by Suzanne Barnhill, MVP.

### To make page numbering continuous, you can use my [Continuous Page Numbering Add-In](http://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#ContinuousPageNumbering) or this macro.

```
Sub ContinuousPageNumbers1()' Jay Freedman
' http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-word/page-numbers-are-all-fouled-up-in-my-large/d188687e-9663-43e0-a450-1dbadc47f09f
' modified to preserve track changes status - idea from Graham Mayor 25 Oct 2017
'   if track changes is locked with password, you can comment out the three lines that have 'Graham Mayor as a tag'
    Dim secNum As Long
    Dim btnCancel ' give user chance to cancel
    Dim bTrackChanges As Boolean
    btnCancel = MsgBox(prompt:="Do you want to reset all of the page numbers in this document to number continuously?", _
        Title:="Are you sure?", _
        Buttons:=vbYesNo)
    If btnCancel = vbNo Then
        MsgBox prompt:="Reset of continuous page numbering cancelled by user!", Buttons:=vbExclamation, Title:="Page Number Reset Cancelled!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
'   Proceed with reset
    bTrackChanges = ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions 'Graham Mayor
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False ' Graham Mayor
    With ActiveDocument
        For secNum = 2 To .Sections.Count
            .Sections(secNum).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary) _
                 .PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = False
        Next
    End With
    ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = bTrackChanges 'Graham Mayor
End Sub
```

Comment: I encountered a document that had some page numbering issues.  I traced the issue to the continuous section break (followed by a next page section break) and the footer information within that "continuous" section.  I agree that the only good reason to use a continuous section break is to switch from single-column to multi-column layout.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to put the continuous break on a paragraph break and then make that paragraph hidden.

You will get a new section without a new page.

This way you can put different page headers while using continuous breaks without always needing a new page.